Problem in merging multiple samples VCF file obtained from Structural variant caller Lumpy
I ran lumpy Sv caller for individual samples to call large structural variants. I ran SVtyper for finding the genotype.
I want to combine multiple samples into 1 VCF with their respective genotype calls. I tried to install SVtools to merge the multiple samples but SVtools installation is creating a problem. I tried running SURVIVOR to combine multiple VCF files but SV caller results don't have the genotypic information due to which it creates a lot of NA values. I tried merging the VCF files through bcftools for multiple samples and am thinking to even merge the genotype VCFs of multiple samples through bcftools. Would this approach be correct? Secondly am facing issues with filtring large structural variants. How should I determine the artifacts vs true variants when filtring the Structural variants. I want to filter the variants by genotype based on genotype as 0/0 for control and the cases being positive genotype. What parameters do we consider when filtring SV's?
